# Create random Objects with primitve members in Java

Tags: java, class, object, serialization, random

I want to test the speed of different Serialization Methods. Therefore I need a class. For my purpose this class has to include only members of primitive data types and each object of the class hast to be around 80Byte size.

I tried following:

```
//Header = 16 Bytes
//long = 8 Byte
// => 80 Byte

public class TestClass implements Serializable {

    private long a = new Random().nextLong();
    private long b = new Random().nextLong();
    private long c = new Random().nextLong();
    private long d = new Random().nextLong();
    private long e = new Random().nextLong();
    private long f = new Random().nextLong();
    private long g = new Random().nextLong();
    private long h = new Random().nextLong();
}
```

And so Im creating the Objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
    TestClass object = new TestClass();
    //do something;
}
```

The problem here is following. This creates only around 846 Objects per ms.
But I need up to 60,000 Objects per ms.
Is there any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe if you didn't create a new Random object for each en every field initialization...

Comment: For sure.
But then the objects arent random.

Comment: Yes they are. Just use **one** Random object to initialize all the fields of all the objects, instead of creating one Random object per field. And anyway, serializing an object takes the same time whether or not the field values are random.

Comment: This works when i want to test the speed of different serializations?
I mean, actually you need to save only one field then.

Comment: Oh okay, i thought with different methods this makes a difference.

Comment: Why assign values to these longs at all? Surely a long with value zero is as fast to serialize as any other value? (Or, pick any other constant value)

Comment: There could potentially be a difference in serializing numbers with different digit count.

Comment: @IvanSkalauh if that's the case, picking random values won't guarantee that you end up with an "around 80Byte" size.

Comment: He meant java object size as I understand (it will be constant).
Serialized string size will of course differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the fields don't matter for most serialization strategies. esp Java Serialization.
However, for serialization strategies where it does matter, random data is probably a bad choice as this will give you far worse results than you might get in reality.

Creating 10 `Random` objects for every actual object is expensive (note Random contains an object as well)

A way around this is to reuse the `ThreadLocalRandom` or just fill the values with some data, even if not too random.

```
static class TestClass implements Serializable {
    private long a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;

    public TestClass(long i) {
        a = i;
        b = a * i;
        c = b * i;
        d = c * i;
        e = d * i;
        f = e * i;
        g = f * i;
        h = g * i;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    for (int t = 0; t < 5; t++) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<TestClass> list = LongStream.range(0, 100_000)
                .mapToObj(TestClass::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.println("Created " + list.size() + " objects in " + time + "ms");

    }
}
```

prints

```
Created 100000 objects in 64ms
Created 100000 objects in 6ms
Created 100000 objects in 6ms
Created 100000 objects in 5ms
Created 100000 objects in 4ms
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the kind of answer i was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call "new Random()" 200000 times, one is enough:

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {

  private long a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
  public TestClass(Random rnd) {
    a = rnd.nextLong();
    // etc.
  }
}
```

and

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
  TestClass object = new TestClass(rnd);
  //do something;
}
```